# Javascript Not Loading in Chrome Extension Script

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

**What I'm trying to do**

It's an extension that, once the page loads, hides a `div` that contains a child with class 'example'.

**What happens**

Nothing. On the `js` page anything that I place is ignored. I have tried using the console and creating page alerts but nothing will work.

**Code**

`manifest.json`:

```
{
"name": "Example",
"version": "1.0",
"default_locale": "en",
"permissions": [
    "http://example.com/*"
    ],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "http://example.com/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "js/jquery/jquery.js",
            "src/inject/inject.js"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

`src/inject/inject.js`:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function(response) {
var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);

                    //Nothing here actually happens
                    alert("Extension loaded");
                    console.log("Extension loaded");

                    //The script that I *want* to happen
                    $('.example-stamp').parent().parent.().parent().hide();
    }
}, 10);
});
```

**Notes**

The `jquery.js` file is the latest download from [jQuery.com](http://www.jquery.com). There are no errors when loading the unpacked extension into Chrome, and nothing - not even errors - appear in the console.

I have been testing it on `http://www.example.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to fix**

Change

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "http://example.com/*"
        ],
```

to

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "http://*.example.com/*"
        ],
```

**Why**

The answer wasn't to do with the `js` code but the manifest.

For some reason, the javascript simply wouldn't inject unless the `content-script` jSON contained the field `http://*.example.com/*`, as `http://example.com` did not work by itself, even if that *was* header URL.

Answer (score 0):

- `chrome.extension.sendMessage` is used to send a message from a content script to a background page or other extension pages. Since you are only defining a content script, that message will not be received, and your callback function will never be invoked.
- Normally you don't need to wait for the document complete status to manipulate the DOM. By default, Chrome will run your content script at `document_idle`, sometime between document ready and just after document complete. See the `run_at` manifest parameter in the definition of [Content Scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- If you really need to run your code when the page finishes loading, you can set `run_at` to `document_start` and listen for the window load event. As you are using jQuery, you can do:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    console.log("Extension loaded");
    $('.example-stamp').parent().parent.().parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: "content_scripts": [{ "matches": ["<all_urls>"], "js": ["content.js"], "run_at": "document_start" } worked for me.. thanks